# Importing a python module to .net - "No module named signal"

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

I'm trying to import a Python module in a C# code like this:

```
        var setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
        var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
        var engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
        var module = engine.ImportModule("mymodule");
```

but I get an error saying "No module named signal", does this mean that IronPython just can't load the signal module, is it OS specific?

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'signal' module is used to handle all that has to do with ... you guessed it: signals. There are special "messages" that the OS send to a process to tell it something: eg. Break, Kill, Terminate, etc... The exact set of message are generally OS specific, but as the [signals](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) python manual page states, python emulates BSD style interface, except for SIGCHLD.

Now, in CPython, the 'signal' module is a built-in as far as I can remember, it could possibly be that IronPython has not implemented it, in fact, a quick google and look on IronPython's site leads to this: [IronPython and CPython differences](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=IPy1.0.xCPyDifferences) (read it, in particular, the extension modules part!)

Possible workaround: edit your module not to use signals when in IronPython